# How to schedule the kivy camera to read the texture continuously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have been trying to create a kivy camera scanner from a number of sources (I would use the zbarcam if I could, but the garden.xcamera module will not import, therefore I am trying to create something similar).

#### Problem

The problem is the camera does not read or update the texture continuously nor is there a way that I can find to capture frame-for-frame from the camera.  This means I only get the texture on initialization.

#### Tried

Firstly, I have tried scheduling an event that will update the texture instance every 0.5 seconds.  I could not get the texture instance of the camera because there is some delay in the camera to load, which caused an error.

Secondly, I created an `on_texture` event in my kv string, but it only reads the texture on initialization.

Thirdly, I tried binding the `on_texture` event a bit later in the python script, by creating a binding function and calling it as a scheduled event.  It did not even get the instance.

Fourthly, I `created_triggers` and `ask_update(callbacks)` to the `_on_texture()` event, but again the script loads to fast before the camera can instantiate crashing the script.

Fifthly, I noticed there is a `kivy.core.video` module that contains a `on_frame` attribute.  Did re-write my script to use it in conjunction with the `kivy.uix.video` module, but noticed that the video cannot run without first loading a video file.

#### Code

```
import kivy
import gi
kivy.require('1.11.1')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from collections import namedtuple
from PIL import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
import time
from gi.repository import Gst
import pyzbar.pyzbar
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

Builder.load_string('''
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<ScanPreview>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint_x: 0.6
    size_hint_y: None
    height: Window.height / 9
    pos_hint: {'top':0.7, 'x': 0.1}
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
    background: 'white.png'
    Label:
        id: sc_data
        text: 'See me...'
<ScanCamera>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    The_Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: root.resolution
        on_texture: root._on_texture(camera)
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Stop'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
''')
class ScanPreview(ModalView):
    pass
class The_Camera(Camera):
    pass
class ScanCamera(BoxLayout):
    resolution = ListProperty([640, 480])
    symbols = ListProperty([])
    code_types = ListProperty(set(pyzbar.pyzbar.ZBarSymbol))
    cam_cam = ObjectProperty(The_Camera())
    the_preview = ObjectProperty(ScanPreview())
    Symb = namedtuple('Symb', ['type','data'])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScanCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cam_cam.play = True
    def _on_texture(self, instance):
        #source: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.zbarcam/blob/develop
        #/zbarcam/zbarcam.py
        print(instance)
        if  not instance.texture == None:
            print(instance.texture)
            self.symbols = self._detect_qrcode_frame(
                texture=instance.texture, code_types=self.code_types)
    def _detect_qrcode_frame(cls, texture, code_types):
        image_data = texture.pixels
        size = texture.size
        #source: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.zbarcam/blob/develop
        #/zbarcam/zbarcam.py
        # Fix for mode mismatch between texture.colorfmt and data returned
        #by
        # texture.pixels. texture.pixels always returns RGBA, so that 
        #should
        # be passed to PIL no matter what texture.colorfmt returns. refs:
        # https://github.com/AndreMiras/garden.zbarcam/issues/41
        pil_image = Image.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,
                                        data=image_data)
        symbols = []
        print(pil_image)
        print(size)
        print(texture.tex_coords)
        print(texture.target)
        codes = pyzbar.pyzbar.decode(pil_image, symbols=code_types)
        for code in codes:
            symbol = CameraClick.Symb(type=code.type, data=code.data)
            symbols.append(symbol)
        print(symbols)
        return symbols

class TestCamera(App):
    title = 'Scan Camera'
    def build(self):
        return ScanCamera()
    def on_stop(self):
        cc = The_Camera()
        print('Stop')
        cc.play = False
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        pass

TestCamera().run()
```

#### Desired result

The camera's texture must continuously update, which will allow the pyzbar and PIL module to decode the texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is how its done, but as I answered my own question I am posting the answer and marking it as such.

#### Answer

So I managed to solve my question by using the example code here: https://kivy-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/kivy/uix/camera.html and mixing in some functions of zbarcam.

By using `self.canvas.ask_update()` in the `on_texture` call it updates the `texture`.  I have added to the code and it now updates the texture continuously and prints the barcode to a togglebutton.  At the moment I have just tested it on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver.  Will test it on android this weekend.

#### Answer code

```
import kivy
import gi
kivy.require('1.11.1')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from collections import namedtuple
from PIL import Image as Img
from kivy.app import App
from gi.repository import Gst
import pyzbar.pyzbar
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.camera import Camera as CoreCamera
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty, \
    BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_string('''
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<ScanCamera>:

<BarcWin>:
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
        color: (1,1,1,1)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0,0,0,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: ''
                with_previous: False
                app_icon: ''
            ActionButton:                
                color: (0,0,0,1)
                background_normal: ''
                Image:
                    source: 'gear_2.png'
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    size: self.parent.width /1.7, self.parent.height/ 1.7
                    allow_stretch: True
            ActionButton:
                color: (0,0,0,1)
                size_hint_x: 0.09
                background_normal: ''
                Image:
                    source: 'dustbin_backgrnd_792521.png'
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    size: self.parent.width /1.7, self.parent.height/ 1.7
                    allow_stretch: True
    ScanCamera:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9, 'right': 1}
        size_hint: [1, 0.8]
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 0
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
            Line:
                width: 2.
                rectangle: (self.x + 40, self.y + 40, self.width/1.1, self.height/1.12)
    ToggleButton:
        id: show_bcode
        pos_hint: {'bottom': 1, 'right': 1}
        size_hint: [1, 0.1]
        color: (1,1,1,1)
        background_color: (0,0,0,0)
        background_normal: ''
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (.18,.36,.61,1) if self.state=='down' else (0,0,0,1) 
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text: 'Hier kom die barcode...'


''')
class BarcWin(FloatLayout):
    cam_cam = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BarcWin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cam_cam = ScanCamera()
    def accept_in(self):
        print('In')
    def accept_out(self):
        print('Out')
class ScanCamera(Image):
    play = BooleanProperty(True)
    index = NumericProperty(-1)
    resolution = ListProperty([Window.width, Window.height])
    symbols = ListProperty([])
    code_types = ListProperty(set(pyzbar.pyzbar.ZBarSymbol))
    Symb = namedtuple('Symb', ['type','data'])
    app_ini_ = ObjectProperty(None)
    got_bcode = BooleanProperty(False)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._camera = None
        super(ScanCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.index == -1:
            self.index = 0
        on_index = self._on_index
        fbind = self.fbind
        fbind('index', on_index)
        fbind('resolution', on_index)
        on_index()
        self.app_ini_ = App.get_running_app()

    def on_tex(self, *l):
        self.canvas.ask_update()
        if not self.texture == None:
            self.symbols = self._detect_qrcode_frame(texture=self.texture, code_types=self.code_types)
            if not self.symbols == []:
                for s in self.symbols:
                    if s.data:
                        if s.data.decode('utf-8') != "":
                            self.app_ini_.root.ids.show_bcode.text = s.data.decode('utf-8')

    def _on_index(self, *largs):
        self._camera = None
        if self.index < 0:
            return
        if self.resolution[0] < 0 or self.resolution[1] < 0:
            return
        #first init of corecamera object
        self._camera = CoreCamera(index=self.index,
                                  resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)

        #when camera loads call _camera_loaded method to bind corecamera method with uix.image texture
        self._camera.bind(on_load=self._camera_loaded)
        if self.play:
            self._camera.start()
            self._camera.bind(on_texture=self.on_tex)
    def _camera_loaded(self, *largs):
        #bind camera texture with uix.image texture that is still equal to None
        self.texture = self._camera.texture
    def on_play(self, instance, value):
        if not self._camera:
            return
        if value:
            self._camera.start()
        else:
            self._camera.stop()
    def _detect_qrcode_frame(self, texture, code_types):
        if not self.got_bcode:
            image_data = texture.pixels
            size = texture.size
            # Fix for mode mismatch between texture.colorfmt and data returned by
            # texture.pixels. texture.pixels always returns RGBA, so that should
            # be passed to PIL no matter what texture.colorfmt returns. refs:
            # https://github.com/AndreMiras/garden.zbarcam/issues/41
            pil_image = Img.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,
                                            data=image_data)
            bcode = []
            codes = pyzbar.pyzbar.decode(pil_image, symbols=code_types)
            #print(pil_image, type(pil_image), dir(pil_image))
            if codes != []:
                for code in codes:
                    symbol = self.Symb(type=code.type, data=code.data)
                    bcode.append(symbol)
                return bcode
            else:
                self.got_bcode = False
                return []
class TestCamera(App):
    title = 'Scan Camera'
    def build(self):
        return BarcWin()
    def on_stop(self):
        cc = ScanCamera()
        print('Stop')
        cc._camera.stop()
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        pass

TestCamera().run()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I was struggling with this issue for a long time!